# mobile device not stretching div to 100% of window size css

Tags: css, mobile

https://balancingpaws.net/

Looks great on a basic browser.

However, if I try to load this page on my mobile device, the entire page doesn't stretch to 100% width. There is about 25% blank space on the right side of the page implying it only stretches to about 75%. I've tried many things. Any recommendations? Help? :).

Comment: i do not see anything wrong with the website on a mobile. Please provide more details. It will help if you can provide a screenshot and also copy paste your html css here so it is easier for us to resolve. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to the following viewport, because yours has an initial-scale=0.41.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You should also correct the mark up because has some errors. You can check them [here](https://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=https%3A%2F%2Fbalancingpaws.net%2F).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I made this change and nothing happened.